# Class initialisation issue python

Tags: python

I have two classes in three files A.py, B.py and C.py

A.py

```
from B import *
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        b = B()
        b._init_()
        print "Hello"
```

B.py

```
from A import *

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        a = A()

    def _init_(self):
        print "hello"
```

when I run C.py having:

```
from B import *

obj = B()
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siddhartha/workspace/link/C.py", line 3, in <module>
    obj = B()
  File "/home/abc/workspace/kinl/B.py", line 5, in __init__
    a = A()
  File "/home/abc/workspace/kinl/A.py", line 4, in __init__
    b = B()
NameError: global name 'B' is not defined
```

Comment: Where is the line `b = B()` ?

Comment: why did you name a method `_init_`?

Comment: @ValentinLorentz just to test the code. That's not the main issue I think

Comment: So, all B objects will create an A object, which will then create a B object, thus creating an A object, … that's probably not what you are trying to do

Comment: @codious I know, that's just the first thing I noticed when reading the code

Comment: You have a circular import issue, search stackoverflow for other questions about this.  Also as Valentin noted, you have a circular logic issue.  Even if your code would run, it would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @BrenBarn how can I come around this problem simply?

Comment: im just trying to use the functionalities in B object in A object and vice versa ortherwise I need to split all my code

Comment: You don't do anything with `a` in `B.__init__()`, so postpone creating the `A` object until you actually need it in some other method.

Comment: that gives the same error as well

Comment: The reason you're getting a `NameError: global name 'B' is not defined` in `A.py` is because you have both a module named `B` and a class named `B`. When you do the import the class name overwrites the module it is in. Change your module names to `a.py`, `b.py`, and `c.py`, and also change your import statements accordingly. i.e. `from b import *`, etc.

Comment: Circular imports work only if you import the whole module. E.g `import A` instead of `from A import *`. Then you would do `a = A.A()` instead of `a = A()` and so on. This will fix the error but you will then get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` because your script will enter an infinite loop. I guess the main question is what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented (but not answered), you have several logical issues in your code.

1. Either import `A` in `B` or vice versa, but not both. That won't work.
2. What is the point of both class wanting to instantiate each other at the first place? This will get you an endless loop.
3. If you instantiate one from the other, you should save the reference to ith, otherwise it will get pointless.
4. The name `_init_` is extremely confusing.
5. Avoid `from ... import *`. It clutters your name space.

I'll make some corrections, assuming this is what you want:

A.py:

```
from B import B # avoid * imports if not needed
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B() # save reference - otherwise it will get lost.
        print "Hello from A.__init__()"
```

B.py

```
# don't import A!
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.do_init()
        # don't call A() - *they* need *us*.
    def do_init(self):  # properly named
        print "hello from B.do_init()"
```

C.py now can do both as needed:

```
from A import A
from B import B

obj1 = A()
obj2 = B()
```